# Issue constructing SQL join query

Tags: sql

I'm trying to construct an SQL query that selects data from both tables but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name,$price 
FROM room 
WHERE capacity>=$partySize 
JOIN room_booking ON room.room_id=room_booking.room_id 
WHERE date_booked<>'$us_date';
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's wrong? you do not like the font used to print the result set? or the name of the room is not spelled right? Seriously how do you expect to get any hep solving your problem if you do not say what it is?

Comment: I think I have put the SQL query in the wrong order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the WHERE clause down to the bottom:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name,$price 
FROM room 
JOIN room_booking ON room.room_id=room_booking.room_id 
WHERE date_booked<>'$us_date' AND capacity>=$partySize
```

Answer (score 2):

Definitely read some more SQL tutorials. You cannot use two WHERE conditions in one query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name,'$price'
FROM room
JOIN room_booking ON room.room_id=room_booking.room_id 
WHERE date_booked<>'$us_date' AND capacity>='$partySize';
```

Also, variables in the query should be quoted.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
SELECT DISTINCT r.name,$price 
FROM room r, room_booking b
WHERE r.capacity>=$partySize 
and r.room_id=b.room_id 
and r.date_booked<>'$us_date';
```

What's $price? is it a value? if variable try r.$price